# Terraform Azure: create a Linux VM from packer image and external data disk

Tags: azure, terraform, packer, terraform-provider-azure, infrastructure-as-code

I have been trying, to no avail, to Terraform the following setup in Azure:

A Linux VM from a Packer-created custom VM image with an additional persistent, managed and encrypted data disk attached to said VM, but lives externally in case I want to recreate the VM with a newer (more updated, secure) version of the custom image, without losing any of the data saved to the external disk (imagine a node in a database cluster). And went on to do the following:

1. Initially, I tried using the `azurerm_managed_disk` and a `azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment` with the VM resource, but the issue is that if you just *create* a disk like this (with `create_option` set to `Empty`) the disk will be unformatted, unpartitioned, and unmounted. Basically unusable unless something script is ran on the VM.
2. My thinking went: ok, I'll just run a `cloud-init` or provisioner block thingie to partition/mount the disk and that's it. But: if I do this, when I rotate the VM, the script will run again and re-format/partition the disk, hence deleting any data I might have saved.
3. I also tried creating a custom image with an additional data disk with Packer, and using `FromImage` in the `azurerm_managed_disk`'s `create_option`, but it turns out [it only works when referencing marketplace images](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/560) and [custom images are not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079735/terraform-creating-vm-from-managed-disk-image-made-in-packer)

The only viable thing I can now think of is going back to approach `2` and make a smarter script that runs only if the attached disk is *not* partitioned.

Is there an alternative approach I'm not seeing? Can someone help me validate this thinking?

My additional concern is regarding encryption in said disks, as I don't know if this will be an issue when adopting either approach.

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/purpose.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can create the Azure VM from a custom image through Terraform, no matter how do you create the image, Packer or other ways, more details see [To provision a Custom Image in Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html#id).

But when you use the custom image and want to encrypted data disk, the problem is coming.

> Disk encryption is not currently supported in the use of custom Linux
>   images.

More details see [Requirements and limitations of Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/encrypt-disks#requirements-and-limitations).

In addition, to mount the data disk to the VM, I think you can use the VM extension to achieve that. And attach the managed data disk to VM, you can just add the [`storage_data_disk`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html#storage_data_disk) block in the VM configuration of Terraform code like this:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
  name                  = "${var.prefix}-vm"
  location              = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.main.id}"]
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

  # Uncomment this line to delete the OS disk automatically when deleting the VM
  # delete_os_disk_on_termination = true


  # Uncomment this line to delete the data disks automatically when deleting the VM
  # delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

  ...

  storage_data_disk {
    name          = "datadisk0"
    vhd_uri       = "${azurestack_storage_account.test.primary_blob_endpoint}${azurestack_storage_container.test.name}/datadisk0.vhd"
    disk_size_gb  = "1023"
    create_option = "Empty"
    lun           = 0
  }

  ...

  tags {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

I am afraid you need to use the custom image id in the vm storage_image_reference. You could use the data azurerm_image to refer your custom image in your group. The code like this:

```
data "azurerm_image" "custom" {
    name = "your_custom_image_name"
    resource_group_name = "your_group"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
    ...

    storage_image_reference {
        id = "${data.azurerm_image.custom.id}"
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! By following your code sample, it suggests I use an unmanaged disk (I take this from the `vhd_uri` option). Would you consider this to be a better approach than using a managed disk?

Also, regarding disk encryption, Terraform does support [providing encryption keys to managed disks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/managed_disk.html#disk_encryption_key), so I guess I could work around the limitation you mentioned through this approach, couldn't I?

Comment: @gvilarino I update the answer to add the code for using the custom image. For the disk encryption, I am afraid you cannot achieve that.

Comment: @gvilarino Do you solve the problem with my answer? If it's helpful you can accept it.

Comment: thanks for your reply. No, I wasn't able to solve the problem completely because trying to use a data disk from a non-marketplace image as an external data disk simply doesn't work in Azure. Additionally, azure-integrated managed disk encryption dosn't work in linux VMs, so secondary bummer.

My solution is to create an empty disk, run a shell script on VM provisioning that partitions, formats and mounts the disk if needs be, and managing encryption via software.